# Valid Javascript: function document.onkeydown(...)?

Tags: javascript, ip-camera

I'm trying to set up a HikVision IP-based camera for some work I'm doing and it refuses to log in to the camera (the login button appears to do nothing).

The *reason* for this, when I break out the Chrome debugger console and investigate a bit deeper, is that the inbuilt `login.js` file (the one supplied by the camera) contains the code:

```
function  document.onkeydown()
{
```

and the browser is complaining that the `.` is an invalid token in this context.

So my first question is simple: is this valid or invalid Javascript?

If it's invalid, I just have to track down the developer for a good talking to :-)

If it's valid, how do I get Chrome to stop complaining so that it can continue to process the rest of the file (including the definition of login function which is what would normally be called when I click on the login button)?

And, if it's not invalid and I don't want to wait around for a vendor fix, is it viable to just replace the login page and the Javascript file with local ones?

In other words, have those two files on my *desktop* (using 127.0.0.1) but have them reference all the other ones on the camera itself (192.0.0.whatever).

So, rather than accessing `http://camera.com/page/login.asp` which contains:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../script/login.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../script/other.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../script/again.js" />
```

I'd instead access `file://login.htm`, which would contain:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="my_good_login.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://camera.com/script/other.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://camera.com/script/again.js" />
```

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript. It looks like they perhaps mistook JavaScript for having similar syntax as Lua. You can't sedate the runtime, since this is a hard syntax error, which will halt execution for the rest of the context.

Comment: @Oka, my thoughts are that I would simply copy the top level page to my local disk and modify it to call a *local* copy of the errant JS code (the local copy being fixed to remove that syntax error). All other scripts other than those two would still be pulled from the camera itself. My proposal wasn't to placate the runtime with the errant JS, rather to put my own (bug-free) JS in. I'll clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with the firmware for some early HikVision cameras, in version 4.x.

The best solution is to upgrade the firmware to 5.2 where the Javascript code in the firmware is fixed.

This can be done with the SPD tool from HikVision itself.

However, if that's not an option, the scheme suggested *should* work. You just have to ensure that you correctly copy the errant firmware files off the camera onto your local box. That means:

- Making an exact copy of the top-level page and errant login Javascript file locally (meaning on your host machine rather than the camera). This is probably as simple as just cut'n'pasting the browser source for both into new files<sup>(a)</sup>.
- *Fixing* the local copy of the errant login Javascript file, replacing `document.onkeydown` with the correct `onkeydown`.
- Ensuring that you use the local top-level page from your browser rather than the on-camera one: this will ensure it uses the local login Javascript file.
- Having that top-level page use your *fixed* login Javascript file: given it is a relative URL, that should work without change.
- Ensuring the local top-level page accesses the other files on the camera: this will entail replacing the relative URLs with absolute ones.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The only worrying possibility is the fact your current top-level page is an ASP one, whereas this process gets its HTML output fro creating the local top-level file. If the ASP file on the camera simply generates the same HTML each time, you'll be file.

However, if it's more complicated than that, you may have to do something tricky like extract the HTML from the camera each time with a script and massage it to change the URL accesses within a local page. Then access that local page from the browser. This *could* be automated but it's starting to get a little more difficult.

So, all in all, an upgrade to later fixed firmware is probably still the best option.